# How to create DjVu format with selectable text?

Tags: conversion, djvu, ocr

DjVu is efficient at compression, but sometimes the text becomes an image and non-selectable. Is there anyway to make sure that the text remains selectable? Which program should I use for this conversion?

Comment: Which OS are you working?

Comment: Linux/ Win 7. Any option in both.

Answer (score 9):

DjVu files are normally image only. From these file sections can be selected as images but not as text¹.

If [OCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) was applied during, or after, the conversion to DjVu. Extra information is stored in the files that associate image areas with text. Only if that was done you can select text from such a file².

Applying OCR to a DjVu file can be done [online](http://www.newocr.com/). If you don't like that you could try [this script](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Help%3aDjVu_files/OCR_with_Tesseract), that uses [Tesseract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract_%28software%29). Or you can go for commercial software such as [Document Express](http://www.caminova.net/en/products/?src=products2.aspx).

¹  <sub>e.g. using  the [djview](http://djvu.sourceforge.net/djview4.html) program.</sub>
² <sub>In theory one could do OCR on the fly in the DjVu viewer, but I don't think any of the currently available viewers can do that.</sub>

Comment: Tesseract is not only an OCR engine, but also an Asgardian artifact of unimaginable power!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [ocrodjvu](http://jwilk.net/software/ocrodjvu) with a selected OCR engine, e.g. tesseract.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [djvuxmlparser](http://djvu.sourceforge.net/doc/man/djvuxml.html#lbAF) to insert XML with OCR text.

You can prepare this XML for example in [FineReader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABBYY_FineReader).